# Binding Text Needs to Reload the Page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core, binding

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms Application. I set a Condition in ViewModel Page, and per as change the Label Text & Image Button Visibility through Binding.

But the Problem is that, when I open the Page, screen is empty, but when I refresh the Page, then it shows the text.

Below is the code for xml and .cs pages.

**IndexViewModel.cs**

```
    public override async Task InitializeAsync(object navigationData)
    {
        var firstname = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("firstname");

        if (firstname == null)
        {
            var RegisteredUserID = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("RegisteredUserID");

            _indexText = "Waiting for Identity to be Issued";
            IsQRScannerVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _indexText = "Your App is Ready";
            IsQRScannerVisible = true;
        }

        await base.InitializeAsync(navigationData);
    }
```

**Bindable Properties**

```
    private string _indexText;
    public string IndexText
    {
        get => _indexText;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _indexText, value);
    }

    public bool IsQRScannerVisible { get; private set; }
```

**IndexPage.xml**

```
<Label
    FontSize="14"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Text="{Binding IndexText}"
    TextColor="White"
    Margin="0,-26,0,150">
</Label>

<ImageButton 
    Source="drawable/qrcode_icon.png"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    WidthRequest = "70"
    HeightRequest = "70"
    MinimumHeightRequest = "70"
    MinimumWidthRequest = "70"
    BackgroundColor="#004B86"
    IsVisible="{Binding IsQRScannerVisible}"
    Command="{Binding ScanVerificationCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the internal field

```
_indexText = "Waiting for Identity to be Issued";
```

doing this bypasses the `PropertyChanged` event.  Instead use the public property

```
IndexTest = "Waiting for Identity to be Issued";
```

Comment: thanks the Text part worked, but Image Button still needs to refresh

Comment: `IsQRScannerVisible` is not calling `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`